# Is subversion installed

Tags: linux

I am creating a bash script in linux, is there a way to detect if subversion is installed on the computer?

I am wanting to detect if its installed and if it isnt prompt the user to install it, I can prompt the user but I cant detect if the program is installed

Comment: You can call `which svn` to see if it's in the `$PATH`, or check for the installed package - that varies by distribution.

Comment: `svn --help; if [[ $? == "0" ]]; then echo "Installed"; fi`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JamieMason/4761049

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PROG=$(which svn 2> /dev/null)

if [ -z "$PROG" ] ; then
    echo "cannot find subversion" 1>&1
else
    echo "Subversion installed at $PROG"
fi
```